# PHP Notice: Undefined index although using try\catch

Tags: php, try-catch

This is my try/catch block in PHP:

```
try
{
    $api = new api($_GET["id"]);
    echo $api -> processRequest();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = array("error" => $e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode($error);
}
```

When there is nothing in the `$_GET["id"]`, I still get the notice error.
How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: use `isset($_GET['id'])` or `array_key_exists('id', $_GET);` .. a million duplicates to count for this question ..

Comment: if (isset($_GET['id'])){     $api = new api($_GET['id']); }

Comment: A PHP notice is not an Exception.

Comment: @sangaran maybe `$api->processRequest();` throws an Exception?

Comment: @dbf maybe it does. But accessing an undefined array index still throws the NOTICE. If the OP wants to avoid it he should set up an appropriate error handler that actually "transform" the notice into an Exception or he can throw an Exception manually when `!isset($_GET['id'])`

Comment: `$api->processRequest();` does throws excetions

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use `isset` function to check if the variable is set or not:

```
if( isset($_GET['id'])){
    $api = new api($_GET["id"]);
    echo $api -> processRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a fast and "dirty" solution, you can use

```
$api = new api(@$_GET["id"]);
```

**Edit:**

Since PHP 7.0 there is a much better and accepted solution: using the [null coalescing operator (??)](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). With it you can shorten your code to

```
$api = new api($_GET["id"] ?? null);
```

and you don't get a notice because you defined what should happen in the case the variable is not defined.

Comment: For the kids at home, this is indeed *dirty* and you should not consider this a solution.

Comment: this is not equivalent to the behaviour the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You have to catch Throwable not Exception:

```
} catch (Throwable $e) {
```

Comment: downvoting because it does not. Throwable as far as I know is for Error and Exception only. original question is for Notice/Warning.

Answer (score 1):

If the absence of id means nothing should then be processed, then you should be testing for the absence of the id, and managing the failure gracefully.

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'] || empty($_GET['id']){
// abort early
}
```

THEN go on and do you try/catch.

Unless of course you were to add some smartness to api() so that is responded with a default id, that you'd declare in the function

```
function api($id = 1) {}
```

So, it "all depends", but try and fail early if you can.

Comment: Note that `empty()` does not fire a notice if the variable is not set. As such, `isset()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the `$_GET` was set

```
try
{
    if(isset($_GET["id"]))
    {
      $api = new api($_GET["id"]);
      echo $api -> processRequest();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = array("error" => $e->getMessage());
    echo json_encode($error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7, we now have the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

```
try
{
    $api = new \Api($_GET['id'] ?? null);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $error = ["error" => $e->getMessage()];
    return json_encode($error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Structure of try...catch**

```
 <?php

try {
    // perform some task
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // jump to this part
    // if an exception occurred
}
```

**You Can Use isset**

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
         $api = new api($_GET["id"]);
         echo $api -> processRequest();
     }else{
          $error = array("error" => $e->getMessage());
          echo json_encode($error);
     }
    ?>
```

Bonus
Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
      $name = $_GET['name']; 
 }else{
      $name = "Name not set in GET Method";
 }
if(isset($_GET['age'])){
      $name = $_GET['age']; 
 }else{
      $name = "<br>Age not set in GET Method";
 }
echo $name;
echo $age;
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).