# Failed to catch exception in PHP

Tags: php, try-catch

I try to use $_GET to pass the date into php else it will use current date.

```
  try {
    $selectedDate = $_GET['date'];
    echo 'try';
    echo $selectedDate;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $selectedDate = date('Y-m-d', time());
    echo 'catch';
  }
```

When I did not pass any input, it shows

> Notice: Undefined index: date
>
> try

Since I have use try catch block, why it would not run catch block?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081677/php-notice-undefined-index-although-using-try-catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a notice. You can check if it exists as below:

```
try {
    if(isset($_GET['date']))
      $selectedDate = $_GET['date'];
      echo 'try';
      echo $selectedDate;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $selectedDate = date('Y-m-d', time());
    echo 'catch';
  }
```

I have added *if(isset($_GET['date']))* to check existence of date.

Answer (score 2):

If you check it carefully.. undefined index is a Notice not an exception..
To avoid this use isset() to check date is set or not

Comment: You should include some code showing what you mean. It's not completely clear what you mean.

Comment: Okay as answer is accepted now.. so next time I will try to add snippet too.. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

**PHP try will not catch any E_NOTICE OR E_WARNING.**

For solving your problem try catch is not required. 
Please use the code I have attached bellow.

```
 try {
      $selectedDate = isset($_GET['date'])? $_GET['date'] : date('Y-m-d', time());
echo 'try';
echo $selectedDate;  

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'catch';

}
```